# Custom full-text index stored in Cassandra

Tags: solr, lucene, cassandra, full-text-search

I've got a situation where I'm using Cassandra for DB and I need full-text search capability.
Now I'm aware of Apache Solr, Apache Cassandra, and DSE search.

However, I do not want to use a costly and proprietary software(DSE search).  The reason I do not want to use Apache Solr is because I don't want to deal with HA, sharding, and redundency for it.  Cassandra is perfect for HA, sharding, and redundency; I would like to store my full-text index in the existing Cassandra DB.

So what I'm looking for is something that will break down a string into its indexable parts.  For example:

`String input = "I like apples and bannanas.";`

```
String tokens[] = makeTokenIndex(input);

//tokens = {"I","like","apples","bannanas","apple","bannana"}
```

Obviously I could split strings on spaces and use the words as index-keys.  But I'm looking for something smarter than that.  Something that can handle plurals, find the root of a word, etc...

Would modifying Apache Lucene be the best solution for this, or is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Cassandra, but I think you're talking about using a Cassandra implementation of Lucene's [Directory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) interface. Lucene uses a Directory to interact with a storage mechanism.

I found a couple of projects that might help:

- [lucene-on-cassandra](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html)
- [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra)

I can't speak with experience about either one, though.