# Storing a Lucene index in a Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, lucene

Is there any way to use Apache Lucene and have it store values and retrieve values from a Cassandra cluster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom full-text index stored in Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552046/custom-full-text-index-stored-in-cassandra)

Answer (score 1):

The hard way: implement a [custom index type](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/index/SecondaryIndex.java) on top of Lucene and teach Cassandra to query it.  There is also [a two year old ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2915) open for this that you could watch.

The expensive way: buy a [DataStax Enterprise](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise/apache-solr) license.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out https://code.google.com/p/lucene-on-cassandra/ . Takes a different approach to the DataStax approach.